# Why is a blank image in Tkinter 1/4 the size I specify?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a canvas in a Python program using Tkinter and putting a solid single color image in it.  (I need an image in there because later I'll be replacing that image with another, which is why I don't just specify the background.)

I specify the size of the canvas and have checked it when the window is open.  It's 640x640.  I specify the blank gray image to be the same size, but it comes up as 320x320, filling only a quarter of the canvas.

I know I can just change the image size to 1280x1280 so the whole canvas will be gray, but when I add other images to the canvas, I don't want to run into similar problems.

Here's the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys
import Tkinter as tk

width = 640
height = 640

guiRoot = tk.Tk()
pWindow = tk.Frame(guiRoot)
BlankImage = None
CanvasMap = None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bmpfile = sys.argv[1]
    print "Working with file: %s" % bmpfile

    BlankImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', (width, height), 'gray'))
    CanvasMap = tk.Canvas(guiRoot, width=width, height=height)
    CanvasMap.create_image(0, 0, image=BlankImage)

    CanvasMap.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)  #later it's 4 columns

    os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
    guiRoot.mainloop()
```

When it runs, it looks like this.

Why is the image only 1/4 size of the canvas?  What do I need to do differently so when I use the same dimensions for the canvas and the image, they'll be the same size?

[image: Image of open window with 1/4 size blank gray image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire image is displayed, but centered at canvas origin `(0, 0)`, this is why you can only see the bottom right `1/4` of it.

You need either to off set the display to the center of the canvas `(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)`, or set the image handle to the top left corner.

Here is one approach:

```
import datetime
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import sys
import Tkinter as tk

width = 640
height = 640

guiRoot = tk.Tk()
pWindow = tk.Frame(guiRoot)
BlankImage = None
CanvasMap = None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bmpfile = sys.argv[1]
#     print "Working with file: %s" % bmpfile

    BlankImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', (width, height), 'gray'))
    CanvasMap = tk.Canvas(guiRoot, width=width, height=height)
    CanvasMap.create_image(width//2, height//2, image=BlankImage)

    CanvasMap.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)  #later it's 4 columns

    os.system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
    guiRoot.mainloop()
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something fairly simple.  Thank you!